# How to create an USSD Mobile Application

Tags: ussd

I want to create a mobile app that can communicate with USSD. We have lot of services we buy using USSD code, I was thinking about building an app to help solve that problem. An app that use to download and use to do their transactions. For example if someone want to buy something using Mobile Money they would use the USSD code which is *144#. If there is a way to create an app that will be able to do the transaction that will be great.

I am thinking of building this app using NativeScript. If there is any other framework that would make me easier I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

My team and I developed a platform called AutoUssd which allows u to do this. Kindly check it out at https://autoussd.com to see if it fits your needs...